# Max handling power for a 10w speaker resistor

Tags: resistors

I have been told that a non-inductive or inductive resistor used for speakers can only handle 10 watts if it is a 10 watt resistor, which makes no sence because they do use even 5 watt resistor in a 160 watt setup. So my question is how do I know how to tell how much they can truly handle before failing or what is the general rule on how much they can use?

Comment: A 10 Watt resistor can handle only 10 Watt. That does make sense. And when a 5 W resistor is used in a 160 W speaker it means that the **maximum power** dissipated in that 5 W resistor will in practice be about 5 W. Because it is a 160 W speaker does not mean all that power goes into that resistor. Some 5 W resistors **can** handle 160 W **but only for a very short time**.

Comment: You hardly want your 10W resistor to fail when you feed it 10.001W

Comment: I've never seen (or heard of) a 'speaker resistor' but I have measured the resistance of a speaker. The speaker coil should be considered an inductor with resistance rather than a resistor. Just measuring its resistance isn't the full story. Also, be very careful when reading the literature - manufacturers tend talk up their product using to statements like 'music power' and 'peak handling power' rather than continuous rms power at particular frequencies. BTW power burn out is not the only failure mode.

Comment: I think you need to explain what you think a _speaker resistor_ is.

Comment: What I mean by a speaker resistor is a wire-wound or a non-inductive. sorry...

Comment: Your edit does not help a bit, inductive or non-inductive is a resistor construction detail. Are you trying to describe a _dummy load_?

Comment: "makes no sence because they do use even 5 watt resistor in a 160 watt setup". Most of the 160W should be going into the _speaker_, not the resistor. Resistors turn power into heat. If all the power went into the resistor there would be nothing left to make sound!

Comment: In the crossover, there is a resistor which would be the 5 watt going to a tweeter. but there is a cap before the resistor. Thus why I would love to know how much they can handle.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a 'speaker' resistor. A resistor is used for whatever purpose it serves. As a general rule resistors are not used at more than 50% to 75% of their maximum rating so there is some assurance of a long life.
There are wire-wound high wattage (5W to 300W) resistors known as 'non-inductive' that are used mostly for RF and audio 'test' circuits, but could offer some benefits for tweeters, by not inducing inductance into the HPF circuit. A typical wire-wound resistor has some inductance, enough to be a problem with high frequency ultrasonic, RF and pulse circuits.
 Most any resistor can take a 50% overload for a second or so. A 10 watt resistor can handle 10 watts, but will last for many decades if run only at 5  to 7 watts. Running a resistor at its maximum rating can cause a 'slow-burn' over 1 or 3 years of continuous use. It may still work OK, but have a discolored look, with any markings burned off.
 For smd resistors, the overload margins are smaller and the 'slow-burn' chance is greater as they do not have enough surface area to dissipate extra heat. They are seldom used at more than 25% to 50% of their wattage rating.